# I need help in perl, how to write a code to get the output of my csv file in the form of a hash

Tags: perl

I need help in **perl**, how to write a code to get the output of my csv file in the form of a **hash.**
Output should look like a hash, no need of creating a hash for output it can be done using array so that I can format my output.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) which provides a method [getline_hr](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV#getline_hr). This method does *not* return the whole CSV file, it only returns a hash of the row. It'll be up to you how to index it if you want one hash with the whole csv.

```
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new;

$csv->column_names( qw/ id col1 col2 / );

while ( not $csv->eof ) {

  my $row = $csv->getline_hr($fh);

  if ( $csv->error_diag ) {
    last if $csv->eof;
    my ( $err, $text ) = $csv->error_diag;
    die $err, $text;
    $csv->SetDiag(0);
    next;
  }

  use Data::Dumper;
  print Dumper $row;

}
```

You'll have to add the row to a hash-database,

```
my %hashdb;
while ( not $csv->eof ) {

  my $row = $csv->getline_hr($fh);

  $hashdb{$row->{id}} = $row;

   ...
```

Comment: "Alanine":"Ala":"A":"GCU, GCC, GCA, GCG":"GCT, GCC, GCA, GCG"
This is one line of file where 0 will be the name of protein,1 will be the 3 letter amino acid,2 will be a reference to an anonymous array of variable size containing dna codons.

Comment: output should look exactly like this...A=> ["Alanine","Ala",["GCT,"GCC,"GCA,"GCG"]]