# How do I remove duplicate values from a CSV file?

Tags: perl

I have to open a csv file and give my output in a form of hash.I have done that part, now i need to put all the contents of my file into a variable minus duplicate.
How can I do that....

```
open FILE, " < abc.csv" or die $!;
# Reading content from CSV file
my @genes = <FILE>;
# Removing the information header from the CSV file contents
shift (@genes); 

print "my %hash = ( \n";

foreach(@genes){
    chomp;
    my @genes = split(':',$_);
    if(@genes != 25){
        next;
    }

    my $amino_acid = join('","',split(/,/,$genes[4]));      


    print "$genes[2]=> [$genes[0],$genes[1],[$group]],\n";

}
```

Comment: You seem confused about which array you use when. `@genetic_codes` and `@genes`. Perhaps you should decide how to use them before you post your code, and avoid posting code that does not do anything.

Comment: What is your intent with trying to change storage format from csv to perl code? Perl code is not an optimal way to serialize your data.

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to be useful to future visitors to the site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need help in perl, how to write a code to get the output of my csv file in the form of a hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918240/i-need-help-in-perl-how-to-write-a-code-to-get-the-output-of-my-csv-file-in-the)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this to remove duplicates in an *array* and to transform it in a *string* :

```
sub uniq {
    return keys %{{ map { $_ => 1 } @_ }};
}

my $string = join " ", uniq @my_array;
print $string;
```